# Ошибка в запросе MySQL Codeignither

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter

Есть запрос, если перевести на нормальный язык то он выглядит вот так

```
SELECT `tm_product`.`id`, `tm_product`.`title`, `tm_product`.`price`, `tm_product`.`old_price`
FROM (`tm_product`)
JOIN `tm_gallery` ON `tm_product`.`id` = `tm_gallery`.`id_product`
```

Выдает ошибку

```
Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous
```

Убираешь join все работает нормально. В codeignither написано так

```
$this->db->select('tm_product.id, tm_product.title, tm_product.price, tm_product.old_price');
$this->db->join('tm_gallery', 'tm_product.id = tm_gallery.id_product');    
$query = $this->db->get('tm_product');
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Ошибка находится в where. А в запросе у вас его нет вообще.

Comment: Приведите запрос полностью. сообщение об ошибке не соотносится с тем, что у Вы нам показываете. Ошибка косвенно связана с этими вашими коде-игнитхерами: "Поле 'id' в условии `where` двусмысленно" - предполагаю, что у Вас в WHERE что-то типа `id = ?` или какое-либо другое выражение с `id`, но у Вас в обоих (!) таблицах есть это поле. так что, как бы, уточните - к которой таблице Вы обращаетесь.